# What is the best way to turn image voting into a game?

Tags: game-design, image, polling

I'm trying to come up with a design for an image voting site that turns the (potentially boring) task of voting on thousands of images into a game. The goal is to get the user to vote on as many image pairs as possible without them getting bored.

My first thought was to use to the different ip addresses of uploaded images and turn the voting into a world journey for the user. The site opens on a world map and is presented a series of image "battles" where they have to choose the winning image out of the pair. Each world region will have anywhere from 10-100 image pairs that the user will vote on. As they complete the image pairs for a region, they are "flown" to another part of the world to keep the game going.

[image]

The goal of the world map approach is to collect the user's opinion on as many image pairs as possible while giving them the sense of: 1- accomplishment (finishing the image pairs of a region) 2- going around the world

I unfortunately ran into a subtle flaw of this approach: Image pair voting will be restricted to particular region...so you can never have an image pair composed of an image from japan against an image from the US.

I was wondering how I could adapt this approach to fix this flaw - ie allow image pairs to be composed of images from all over the world instead of a particular region only?

Or even if you could come with a different design that accomplishes the same goals (collect as many votes as possible while keeping the user motivated and not bored)

Thanks for your time

Comment: Wouldn't you just change it to travel around their own region?

Comment: Not exactly. I'd like them to vote on all images in the system (ie in the world). So to have them move around as much as possible is the ideal case

Comment: the restriction comes from the current design of the world map, I was asking for ways of modifying that design to remove that restriction. In other words, how would I create a world map voting game where the image pairs can come from different parts of the world and still be a "journey" around the world. Thanks

Comment: I'd be careful asking for users to vote on country vs country images. Patriotic people might always pick their own country to win for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating your image pairs, one of the images will always be from the current region, the second will be from a random region. They are not labeled as such, the region information for the images is hidden from the user. At the end of the voting, the region other than the current region with the most votes is the place the player "travels" to next.